# How to use CSS to make a row with 3 columns stack on top to create 2 columns

Tags: css

I think my image illustrates what I would like to do here,

Please note that I will also need column 1 to slightly overlap column 2 and 3.

I will also have some images in column 3 that need to be center aligned in line with its left border. (I am not asking for help on these, just stating so you understand what display types I should use)

Thanks people!

[image]

I've tried with Valds method but unfortunately I can't get it to suit my needs.

[image: Valds result]

I should have been more explicit, but I require that the image on the far left (column 1) is always in line with the bottom of column 3.
[image]

Comment: What  have you tried so far? Any attempts?

Comment: I've spent the last hour messing around and I think a grid system is the way to go, I'm just trying to figure out how to use them as they're a little more complicated than what I normally deal with...

Comment: Could you please add your code to your question and let people know where you stuck?

Comment: please tell me if the grid system is the best and I will come back with code in whatever display method you recommend. I just want to know what I should be focusing on

Comment: You only need to achieve your outcome result, or you want to pass from "start" to "outcome" by keeping the same DOM ?

Comment: to use the same DOM to achieve the outcome

Answer (score 0):

(This is just one of many ways to do it)

Just add or remove the outcome class to switch from layout 1 to layout 2

```css
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.columns div {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100px;
}
.outcome div:nth-child(2), .outcome div:nth-child(3) {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div>Column 1</div>
  <div>Column 2</div>
  <div>Column 3</div>
</div>

<div class="columns outcome">
  <div>Column 1</div>
  <div>Column 2</div>
  <div>Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this now - would a grid system not have worked as well?

Comment: Hi Vald, I've just tried your method and edited the post. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Below uses css grid to create your desired result. Were you wanting the three columns to change into the result below come a break point?

```css
.container{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* 2,1ft divides up all available space from left to right into two.*/
  grid-template-rows: 30vh repeat(1, 1fr);
}
.image{
  grid-row: 1 / -1; /* You can use -1 if you want it to go to the end of the grid.*/
  grid-column: 1 / 2
}
.headerTxt{
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;  
}
.imageTxt{
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.flx{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image flx">COLUMN 1</div>
   <div class="headerTxt flx">COLUMN 2</div>
  <div class="imageTxt flx">COLUMN 3</div>
</div>
```